# "snap" apps in Debian 12 Plasma5 change the cursor

Tags: plasma5, snap, cursor

I had to install vlc and cctv-viewer using "snap" in Debian 12, as that OS doesn't support rtsp (real-time streaming protocol). The Plasma themed cursor is fine until it enters the app area, when it becomes tiny and hard to see.

Here's the cursor on the window titlebar:
[image: Plasma5 cursor outside snap app]
... and here's the cursor pointing at the "Video" menu:
[image: Plasma5 cursor inside snap app:]

How to keep snap applications from changing the cursor, please?

Comment: An operating system doesn't care about rtsp. And there's more than one way to install VLC on Debian.